# Data Attribute does not apply css after modify the value by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

I would like to implement a check list by list item (li). I use data-checked attribute to keep the checking state. I set the icon color with css selector ('true' = black and 'false' = white color).

It work fine when the page display, all tasks show the white icon as their default data-checked value is 'false'. But when I click the list items, the data-checked value is modified to 'false', but the color does not change to black.

I have checked the value by alert them. They are properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li data-id='1' data-checked='false' onclick='toggle_task(this);'>
    <i class='fs fa-check'></i>
    <span>Task A</span>
  </li>
  <li data-id='2' data-checked='false' onclick='toggle_task(this);'>
    <i class='fs fa-check'></i>
    <span>Task B</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick='show_checked();'>Done</button>
```

CSS:

```
ul li[data-checked='true'] i:first-child {
  color: #000000;
}
ul li[data-checked='false'] i:first-child {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function toggle_task(sender) {
  if ($(sender).data('checked').toString == 'true') {
    $(sender).data('checked','false');
  } else {
    $(sender).data('checked','true');
  }
}
function show_checked() {
  $(li).each(function() {
    var text = $(this).data('id').toString() + ': ' + $(this).data('checked').toString();
    alert($(this).data('checked'));
  });
}
```

Comment: Didnt understand the Question . please tell what you want

Comment: prove a working fiddle please..

Comment: I want to set the icon color by css & data-attribute that is changed by javascript (after it was clicked). For the example, clicking the list item will toggle the data-checked value between 'true' and 'false'. The icon should change color as the css set but it is not.

Comment: just toggle a class. Why do you want to get a data attribute involved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have become confused between the [HTML data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) (which you are using as part of your CSS selector) and the [jQuery data method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) which stores arbitrary JavaScript objects associated with the element but outside of the DOM. The confusion probably comes from this-

> .data( key ) Returns: Object Description:
>
> Return the value at the
>   named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as
>   set by data(name, value) **or by an HTML5 data-* attribute.**

The method allows you to read data from HTML 5 data-* attributes if there is no value with that key in the jQuery collection, but not to set it.

What you want to do is use the [jQuery attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this-

```
function toggle_task(sender) {
  if ($(sender).attr('data-checked') === 'true') {
    $(sender).attr('data-checked','false');
  } else {
    $(sender).attr('data-checked','true');
  }
}

function show_checked() {
  $('li').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).attr('id') + ': ' + $(this).attr('data-checked');
    alert($(this).attr('data-checked')); //Consider using console.log rather than alert here
  }); //Fixed your jQuery selector - required quotes for li element - is not a JavaScript variable
}
```

As a bonus the attr method returns a string and not an object - so you can dispense with the toString calls.

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do visually, but if you want to have a coloured block need to the element indicating if it is checked or not (in which case the <i> element is not the most semantically appropriate) you also need to update your CSS-

```
/* These need to be background-color, not color */

ul li[data-checked='true'] i:first-child {
  background-color: #000000;
}
ul li[data-checked='false'] i:first-child {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

/* Also need to add these styles to actually see the empty elements */

.fa-check {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.5em;
    width: 0.5em;
}
```

I have created JSFiddles of [your original code](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/VVQf7/) and [the updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/VVQf7/3/) which is worked as I *think* you want it to.

Please, please, please consider using unobtrusive event handlers with jQuery using the [jQuery on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) rather than having inline "onclick" attributes. This keeps your JavaScript logic separate from your HTML content, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I have relly confused between the HTML data-* attributes and the jQuery data method.