# CSS not changing after altering data attribute tag with AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, html

I am designing a website that shows the availability of a resource using either a green or red colour indicator based upon the availability field of a connected MySQL database table.

The item I am looking to alter is a span element:

```
 <span class="equipment" data-id="1" data-available="1" data-location="0-0"></span>
```

This is being parsed by JQuery for the data attributes for availability and location, and compared to a MySQL database with AJAX post to note changes in availability which should be propagated to the webpage, changing the colour of the indicator as per the below CSS.

```
.equipment[data-available='1'] {
 background-color: rgb(0,226,0); //green
 }

.equipment[data-available='0'] {
 background-color: rgb(226,0,0); //red
 }
```

The AJAX request, seen below, recognizes changes from the database and returns from the php file successfully, returning just the new availability (0 or 1). If I console.log() the php post URL, the value returned by  *equipment_span.data("available")* and stored in *old_avail* appears to have updated to the new value desired after a database change occurs. However, the changes to this aren't reflected in a colour change to the indicator.

```
function update_avail() {

    $('.equipment').each( function () {
        var equipment_span = $(this);

        var old_avail = equipment_span.data("available");
        var loc = equipment_span.data("location");

        $.post('avail.php?a='+old_avail+'&l='+loc, function(new_avail) {
            if(new_avail != old_avail) {
              equipment_span.data("available", new_avail);  
            }
        })
    })
}
```

If anyone could offer any pointers as to what is going wrong, that would be great as this has been annoying me for hours at this stage.

Comment: Have you inspected the rendered HTML after the update? Does it, in fact, have `data-available='0'`? And I would use double quotes, but I'm not sure if it matters (`.equipment[data-available="0"]`)

Comment: use .attr instead: http://jsfiddle.net/o14jh99a/ Similar question (and why) (to be honest, it sounds like a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152398/data-attribute-does-not-apply-css-after-modify-the-value-by-jquery . In a nutshell, only .attr allows you to EDIT the value of an attribute, while .data doesn't, it just reads and store it somewhere else, but doesn't modify the dom at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this line:

```
equipment_span.data("available", new_avail);
```

When jquery manages the data attributes it does so in memory and not "on the page", so if you inspect the page it will show data-available="whatever it was on page load"

You need to do:

```
equipment_span.attr("data-available", new_avail);
```